# Highcharts y-axis labels removed after zoom out

Tags: javascript, charts, highcharts, angular2-highcharts

I have used [highcharts](https://www.highcharts.com/) 7.0.2 version.

In my application initially, charts line charts are bound properly but after zoom in and zoom out it will create an issue on axis labels.

Below are some snaps for the same.

Also, I have used the [zooming](https://www.highcharts.com/docs/chart-concepts/zooming) on 'xy' axis.

```
 chart: {
    zoomType: 'xy'
    }
```

**1) Chart before zoom out**

[image]

**2) Charts after zoomout**
[image]

[image]

Fiddle demo: https://jsfiddle.net/ukLaqtyv/.
To reproduce the issue you have to do very large zoom.

**Chart with zoom**
[image]

**After click on reset zoom button**
[image]

Comment: We won't be able to help you unless you show some code. Please create a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/)/[codepen](https://codepen.io) example and post the link in your question.

Comment: I have added a jsfiddle link and scenario for reproducing the issue in the description.

Comment: FYI just tried on chrome ,IE and firefox, only chrome bug.

Answer (score 1):

This problem looks like a bug, so I reported it on Highcharts github: https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/issues/10516

To workaround, you can set `tickPositions` again by the `update` method:

```
yAxis: {
    events: {
        afterSetExtremes: function(e) {
            if (
                typeof e.userMin == 'undefined' &&
                typeof e.userMax == 'undefined'
            ) {
                this.update({
                    tickPositions: this.tickPositions
                });
            }
        }
    }
},
```

**Live demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/yx9wtf2p/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/yAxis.events.afterSetExtremes

Comment: Only work for the 1st time and after clicking on 'reset zoom' button, Zoom in is not working properly.

Comment: Hi @Maulik sojitra, Yes, you are right. Please check this workaround: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/8nprost0/